# Trying to compare new users vs old users preference use of bookmarks vs tabs

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to evaluate new vs old users of a browser. The users have taken a survey with things like how long have they been using the browser etc.. We also have an events table with recorded events like choosing a bookmark or opening a tab.  I would like to compare the difference in new vs old users  preference for using either feature.

I know how to get the users but I having a hard time with the join and subqueries. This is the query that I have and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Not sure if I should use a case statement.

```
SELECT
FROM (
    SELECT user_id, count(q1) 
    FROM survey 
    WHERE q1 like '%0%' 
    LEFT JOIN on events
    WHERE survey.id = events.id 
    AND event_code =10
    Group BY user_id

SELECT user_id, COUNT(* )
    FROM events 
    WHERE event_code = 10 AS BOOKMARK_CHOOSE
    GROUP BY user_id
    AND BOOKMARk_CHOOSE > 0;
```

example data: 
q1=How long have you used Firefox? 0 = less than 3 months, 6 = over 5 years. 
Bookmark_choose = when user chooses a to use a bookmark. Its a time stamp

END RESULT: I want to compare average number of bookmark_choose between new and old users.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Please state the output that you are looking for